# How this is done in jQuery that both "jQuery(...)" as well as "jQuery.post(...)" are correct and work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

In jQuery we can use the dollar sign in a way it behaves as a function:

```
   $(selector);
```

we can also use it in a way it behaves as an object, e.g.:

```
  $.post(...);
```

I'm trying to understand how this is done (and simultaneously how JavaScript works). The browser says that typeof($) (when $ means jQuery) is "function". Can anyone give me a simplest possible code (in plain [pure] JS) where one defines some variable (which can refer to a function, object or whatever in JS), let's say jQ, such that both codes:

```
  jQ(some_args);
```

as well as

```
  jQ.method(args);
```

are correct and work as we wish? For example, let jQ(selector) returns the collection of DOM objects compatible with selector; and let jQ.wri(text) just does: console.log(wri).
I'm interested in a less complicated example. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Functions are objects and can be given properties just like any other object.

Comment: Maybe I'm a beginner, but all my efforts to do so failed (I tried with prototype and in a function body to define a method inside a function, but then whenever I invoked jQ.method, JS crashed at this moment).

Comment: @piotr: Sounds like you have specific code which is failing in a specific way, which itself can be a meaningful Stack Overflow question.

Comment: `let x = function() { ... }; x.foo = function() { ... }`

Comment: @Pointy: That indeed works!!! THANK YOU!

Comment: @piotr you should update your question with that information.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward, you just have to set the property after creating the function:

```js
function Foo (argument) {
  console.log("called main Foo with", argument)
}

Foo.bar = function (bargument) {
  console.log("called bar with", bargument)
}

Foo('hello')
Foo.bar('is it me you ar looking for?')
```

You can also use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set more metadata on the property, such as modifiable or enumerable, etc.

Functions are in most respects objects in javascript, and as you can see have modifyable properties. You could [`seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [`freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object to prevent properties from being added or changed, but Functions are not sealed by default. Numbers also have properties, but they *are* sealed/frozen by default. Functions are special from other objects in that they are the only way to make an object "callable", and that is presumably why they don't have a [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) `object`, like arrays do.